# Jquery for Wordpress worked on my localhost but after ulploading the files it stopped working?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I installed Jquery for Wordpress in a Wordpress page in my localhost:

http://localhost/brianfunshine.com2/

Images were properly being displayed in a lightbox

http://alex-chen.net/wordpress/

But when I uploaded the files to a server, Jquery for Wordpress stopped working.

I  just uploaded the Wordpress theme and the plugin.

I'm not sure which code to provide.

Please let me know how to solve this.

The code of the link of the image (in this case is a video):

```
<div><a href="#second2"><img src="http://www.howieolson.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/howie-olsen-welcome-video.jpg" alt="Welcome To High Output" width="220px" height="120px" /></a></div>
<div id="second2" style="display: none;"><object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="480" height="385" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/N172nW_U39g?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="480" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/N172nW_U39g?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object></div>
```

**EDIT:**

The plugin says that it looks by itself for direct links. And it does when I use it from my localhost.

When I upload the files I have to assign the class: "fancybox" to the links in order to make it work.

I don't know Javascript but I think the plugin searches for direct links here:

```
// Load FancyBox with the settings set
function mfbfw_init() {

    $settings = mfbfw_get_settings();

    echo "\n"."\n"."<!-- Fancybox for WordPress v". $settings['version'] ." -->"."\n";

    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    <?php if ($settings['jQnoConflict']) { ?>jQuery.noConflict();<?php } echo "\n" ?>

    jQuery(function(){

        <?php // This copies the title of every IMG tag and adds it to its parent A so that fancybox can use it ?>
        jQuery.fn.getTitle = function() {
            var arr = jQuery("a.fancybox");
            jQuery.each(arr, function() {
                var title = jQuery(this).children("img").attr("title");
                jQuery(this).attr('title',title);
            })
        }

        // Supported file extensions
        var thumbnails = 'a:has(img)[href$=".bmp"],a:has(img)[href$=".gif"],a:has(img)[href$=".jpg"],a:has(img)[href$=".jpeg"],a:has(img)[href$=".png"],a:has(img)[href$=".BMP"],a:has(img)[href$=".GIF"],a:has(img)[href$=".JPG"],a:has(img)[href$=".JPEG"],a:has(img)[href$=".PNG"]';

    <?php if ($settings['galleryType'] == 'post') {

        // Gallery type BY POST and we are on post or page (so only one post or page is visible)
        if ( is_single() | is_page() ) { ?>

        jQuery(thumbnails).addClass("fancybox").attr("rel","fancybox").getTitle();

    <?php }

    // Gallery type BY POST, but we are neither on post or page, so we make a different rel attribute on each post
    // (optimized based on sugestions from http://mentalfruition.com/)
    else { ?>

        var posts = jQuery('.post');

        posts.each(function() {
            jQuery(this).find(thumbnails).addClass("fancybox").attr('rel','fancybox'+posts.index(this)).getTitle()
        });


    <?php }

    }
```

Comment: I'd first check that all the files are still being loaded correctly - are you using hardcoded directories or getting them dynamically?

If you could post the code you use to initialise jQuery and the light box, that would help

Comment: @dpmguise the plugin says that it is automatically applied to all image and video links. (what do you mean by handcoded or dynamic directories?)

Comment: Sorry, How did you install jQuery? was an automatic process or did you put the code in yourself?

Comment: I uploaded by myself into the plugin directory. (Please see the edit, I got it working, but I still need to solve the problem)

Comment: I see no Javascript errors on http://alex-chen.net/wordpress/2011/01/video-voice-demo/ and the click here link does open a fancybox. (Chrome Browser on Mac)

Comment: @Bill N because I assigned the class=fancybox to the link (it only works like that). Please try clicking again (I removed the class). I'm trying to figure out why the plugin is not being applied to all direct links like it does in my localhost

Comment: @janoChen I see it now. JQuery is working, but for some reason it's not applying the fancybox class to your image link like it should be.

Comment: @Bill N Yeah weird, the only difference is the URL. Could this be the problem (please check my edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugins selector is using has(img) to determine if the fancybox class should be added to the link.

```
var thumbnails = 'a:has(img)[href$=".bmp"],a:has(img)[href$=".gif"],a:has(img)[href$=".jpg"],a:has(img)[href$=".jpeg"],a:has(img)[href$=".png"],a:has(img)[href$=".BMP"],a:has(img)[href$=".GIF"],a:has(img)[href$=".JPG"],a:has(img)[href$=".JPEG"],a:has(img)[href$=".PNG"]';


jQuery(thumbnails).addClass("fancybox").attr("rel","fancybox").getTitle();
```

has(img) is looking for an img tag inside of the link (a tag), not linking to an image as you are doing with the following:

```
<a href="http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/4065/screenshot2lx.png">click here</a>
```

It requires something like the following to work automatically:

```
<a href="http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/4065/screenshot2lx.png"><img src="<thumbnail url>" /></a>
```

Comment: Hey you are right! but why the youtube video is not being displayed: <div><a href="#second2">`<img src="http://www.howieolson.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/howie-olsen-welcome-video.jpg" alt="Welcome To High Output" width="220px" height="120px" /></a>`?

Comment: O I think it doesn't support links with an id in the href part. But why it works in my local host?

Comment: The video link on http://alex-chen.net/wordpress/category/voice-video-demos/ works for me.